# Unable to derive the probability density function for MLE computation

Tags: probability

Question is as such:
Company manufactured objects from 1 to N, with N objects in total. One of the objects is selected at random, and serial number of the object is 888. I am asked to find the MLE estimate of N.

I now want to find the pdf of this population, so that I can derive the MLE estimate. My first thought is that the probability distribution function is just $\frac{1}{N}$, but if I choose that and I differentiate and equate to 0 to find the MLE estimate, the equation cannot be solved.

Comment: I don't know how to go about finding such but [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) is what Wiki has to say about it.

Comment: If you think about the set of admissible values of $N$, then any differentiation (wrt the parameter of interest) would be ruled out immediately. And why is it a pdf, and not a pmf?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am actually still in the midst of learning the whole concept of MLE, and thus not too sure how to go about it. What I'm learning is to take the likelihood / loglikelihood, which i observed from previous examples that it is the pdf. I could be wrong though.

Comment: In general you are maximizing the likelihood, and you need to know the parameter space - now the parameter $N$ is discrete, not continuous, so you are not using the same calculus approach for the continuous parameter space optimization problem. The likelihood function, evaluated at different parameters value will form a sequence and you try to see if there is any tendency between them (actually this is like the spirit in doing differentiation - but now you are doing successive difference / ratio to find the trend)